# Display multiple columns SQL query into PL/SQL stored procedure

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I have a SQL query from which select multiple columns from "db_cache_advice". I want to create a PL/SQL stored procedure from the script.

Here is the SQL script, can someone show me a small sample from which i can pick up...

```
select name, size_for_estimate, size_factor, estd_physical_read_factor
  from v$db_cache_advice;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This is nowhere near enough information. You need to a) decide what you want to do. b) attempt to do it and then come back when you have some problems, please read the [faq] _and_ [ask].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are asking whether we can select multiple columns in pl/sql stored procedure or not..

then well yes, we can select multiple columns as well..

you have to give multiple variable list with respect to number of column you are selecting -

```
select name, size_for_estimate, size_factor, estd_physical_read_factor
into l_name, l_size_for_estimate, l_size_factor, l_estd_physical_read_factor
  from v$db_cache_advice;
```

please note variable should be in sync, datatype should be match with column value fetching ...